# Super long Visual Studio pauses connected to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Ever since I connected to TFS, Visual Studio has started pausing for very long periods of time (30-60 seconds), even when doing things that probably shouldn't be hitting the server. It eventually comes back, but it's very disruptive. The server is not local, but I'm told that it's not really doing much, nor does it have a lot of traffic.

Has anyone experienced this, and does anyone know what I might do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Try setting your source control plugin to "none" and see if the pauses go away.

Comment: I work connected to TFS (elsewhere in the company network) and don't experience those pauses. So those pauses are not "usual".

Comment: Long pauses in network activity are usually an indication of dns lookup issues.  Try flushing your DNS cache (ipconfig /flushdns) and seeing if that resolves things.  Or ping the server and see what happens.
TFS is accessed via web services under the covers so you could also use fiddler and watch the network activity and see if there are any unusual responses occurring.

Comment: Mike, what kind of access do you have to your TFS server(s)? Try getting he Administrative Reporting Pack deployed to your TFS reporting services instance (assuming you deployed RS).  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/07/12/administrative-report-pack-for-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, all. I tried doing the dns flush on my local box. It didn't really help. I can ping the server without any delays. I'm going to see if we can get the admin reports installed. One thing I did want to point out was that I can reproduce the problem consistently by deleting a directory within source control. Does that shed any light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fiddler, I saw that each operation that caused a pause involved downloading a 3MB repository.asmx file. The server doesn't have a great upload speed, so that was causing the delay. I had a bunch of stuff checked out, and as I checked it in, that file got smaller and smaller. Now it's down to about 4KB, and the delay is only a couple of seconds.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: small checkins often are usualy the order of the day :)

Comment: But a 30second delay to upload a 3MB repository file?!  If you still ahve the fiddler output it'd be interesting to see time-to-last-byte for that upload.  You could look at the IIS logs, but there is definitely opportunity for improvement there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't. It's coming from a home broadband line, so it's not that surprising.